# Regular Expression Exact match numbers characters digits special characters

Tags: regex

i am looking for a regular expression to have EXACT 8 ocurrences,
these occurences may be characters, numbers, special characters,etc..

I thought about this regex: .{8}
But this allows you to enter more and is not an exact match,

Who could help me?
Greetings

Comment: Learn how to use anchors! They're really helpful :)

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html!

Answer (score 3):

You must add anchors to have an exact match:

```
^.{8}$


^   #begin of the string
$   #end of the string
```